# Fixed header that snaps underneath main fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

I have been working on a problem with some other developers on this site with a fixed header problem.

I have now updated the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/

The Problem

1) When scrolled down the page the yellow block needs to snap to the red block.

Please view the code and demo, any help would be much appreciated.

```
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($('body').scrollTop() > offset.top + additionalPixels) {
        $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }


});
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might learn something from this article on [Persistent Headers](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/) over on CSS-tricks website

Comment: Check out this page, you can use multiple headers similar to ios scrollview (music list) where the header or divider will stick to the top of the page then be replaced once a new header/divider reaches the top 
http://www.teamdf.com/web/showcasing-jquery-list-with-a-fake-iphone/147/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues. You didn't include a fixed class so I added that in this:

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top:52px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f95sW/4/)**

But more importantly, you need to change your math to:

```
if ($('body').scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the .fixed class

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left:0;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/2/